# Replacement for three terminal capacitor

Tags: capacitor, motherboard

One of capacitors on my IBM 5150 motherboard burned out, so, I'm looking the way to replace it. I tried to google to identify this capacitor:
[image]
It looks like it's a 10 μF 16V three terminal capacitor, but I was unable to find anything like this on ebay, so, probably, I'd better to make a replacement using two capacitors, but, I have no idea how to make it. I would very appreciate any help because I really want to resurrect this motherboard.

here is another image (i decided to cut it from pcb, because I don't want to do something irreparable with my soldering iron, as I understand this board has several internal layers):

[image]

Thank you very much!

P.S.> I've made one more picture which is representing polarity. So, it's getting -12V on outer pin.
[image]

Comment: You might be better looking for faulty/broken IBM 5150 computer parts, and using them for salvage (e.g. random google search found [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/292455741812)). However without knowing why the cap burnt out, putting a new one in might achieve nothing but burning out another capacitor. The part that goes bang is usually the weak link in a much larger failure.

Comment: write down all the info from the burned cap, then remove the yellow shell to see what is inside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only a single capacitor, not a 2 in 1 package.
The outer leads are internally connected as a feed-through.
From this [Murata Doc](https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/products/emc/emifil/knowhow/20to22.ashx):
[image]
So if you can't find a similar one to replace it with, you can loop a piece of wire between the outer 2 pins and connect a 2-terminal cap from the middle pin to that wire.
**Pay attention to polarity !!**
You will obviously lose the noise-suppression & other characteristics that the correct three-terminal cap would have given you though.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I'll try to find the same capacitor, but want to be sure that it wont be burned too, so, probably, I'm going to make some experiments with regular 2-terminal capacitor. I've added one more image which shows that this capacitor is getting -12v on one of outer terminal and I'm kind of confused about polarity. So, I have  to connect an electrolyte's positive terminal to the middle pin, the negative to the outer one and then loop a piece of wire to another outer pin, am I correct? Thank you!